# Swift - WhatsApp like keyboard dismiss

Tags: swift, xcode, keyboard, whatsapp, dismiss

I'm developing a message app but I want to dismiss the keyboard when pushing it with my finger.

I know that can be done with

```
keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

But I don't know how to change tableview's constraints while moving the keyboard (like WhatsApp app for iOS).

Can anyone help me with it?

EDIT:

This is what I already have:

I have a simple UITableView to show my messages

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    var celda = UITableViewCell()
    
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    
    if message.owner == 0{
        
        celda =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageOther")!
    }else{
        
        celda =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageMine")!
    }
    
    let fondoView = celda.viewWithTag(1)
    fondoView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
               
    let messageLabel = celda.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    messageLabel.text = message.text
    
    let fecha = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(message.date))
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    
    let dateLabel = celda.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: fecha)
    
    return celda
}
```

And in my viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    messagesTableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    
    getMessages()
}
```

And the keyboard hides pushing it with the finger, that's all I have so far, but I don't know how to make my UITextField follows the movement of the keyboard, like WhatsApp and iMessage do, also start pushing it from the UITextField instead of the keyboard.

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: what did you try? could you please share your code what you've done?

Comment: Sure! I added more information

Comment: @Jorge I am having the same issue. did you find a fix? the keyboard will drag down but the text input which is in a vstack will not move with it

Comment: bro you find any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You can set the keyboard Dismiss Mode to `onDrag` in `ViewDidLoad` as below.

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Check if this is the kind of behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you! I wanted but with interactive instead to follow the movement of the finger